# How to mock IRepository<T>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unit-of-work

I want to mock a unit of work interface with repositories inside for unit test purpose. So far I am able to do it like below.

```
namespace Liquid.Service.UnitTest
{
    using Liquid.DataAccess.Interface;
    using Liquid.Domain;
    using Domain.Interface;
    using Moq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class Helper
    {
        internal Mock<IUnitOfWork> MockUnitOfWork(ICollection<Dummy> dummies = null,
            ICollection<ProductType> productTypes = null)
        {
            dummies = dummies ?? new List<Dummy>();
            productTypes = productTypes ?? new List<ProductType>();

            var dummyRepositoryMock = MockDummyRepository(dummies);
            var productTypeRepositoryMock = MockProductTypeRepository(productTypes);

            var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.DummyRepository)
                .Returns(dummyRepositoryMock.Object);
            unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.ProductTypeRepository)
                .Returns(productTypeRepositoryMock.Object);

            return unitOfWorkMock;
        }

        private Mock<IDummyRepository> MockDummyRepository(ICollection<Dummy> dummies)
        {
            var dummyRepositoryMock = new Mock<IDummyRepository>();

            dummyRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.FindById(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns((int arg1) => dummies.Where(x => x.Id == arg1).SingleOrDefault());

            dummyRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Dummy>()))
                .Callback((Dummy arg1) => dummies.Add(arg1));

            return dummyRepositoryMock;
        }

        private Mock<IProductTypeRepository> MockProductTypeRepository(ICollection<ProductType> productTypes)
        {
            var productTypeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IProductTypeRepository>();

            productTypeRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.FindById(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns((int arg1) => productTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == arg1));

            productTypeRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ProductType>()))
                .Callback((ProductType arg1) => productTypes.Add(arg1));

            return productTypeRepositoryMock;
        }
    }
}
```

You see that I've created two method to mock DummyRepository and ProductTypeRepository but because it has same implementation, I think it is redundant for every repositories I have.
Below is the Repositories and IRepository code.

```
namespace Liquid.DataAccess.Interface
{
    using Liquid.Domain;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public interface IDummyRepository : IRepository<Dummy>
    {
    }

    public interface IProductTypeRepository : IRepository<ProductType>
    {
    }

    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IList<TEntity> GetAll();

        Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();

        Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        IList<TEntity> PageAll(int skip, int take);

        Task<List<TEntity>> PageAllAsync(int skip, int take);

        Task<List<TEntity>> PageAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, int skip, int take);

        TEntity FindById(object id);

        Task<TEntity> FindByIdAsync(object id);

        Task<TEntity> FindByIdAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, object id);

        void Add(TEntity entity);

        void Update(TEntity entity);

        void Remove(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

How can I use a same method to mock every repositories implementation which inherits IRepository?

UPDATE :
The test is just a simple add and check like below.

```
    [Test]
    public void ProductTypeService_Add()
    {
        // GIVEN
        var productTypeData = new ProductType()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "ProductType1"
        };

        // WHEN
        var unitOfWorkMock = new Helper().MockUnitOfWork();
        var productTypeService = new ProductTypeService(unitOfWorkMock.Object);
        productTypeService.Add(productTypeData);
        unitOfWorkMock.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges());

        // THEN
        Assert.That(productTypeService.FindById(1) != null);
        Assert.That(productTypeService.FindById(2) == null);

        // WHEN
        var productTypeData2 = new ProductType()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Description = "ProductType2"
        };

        productTypeService.Add(productTypeData2);

        // THEN
        Assert.That(productTypeService.FindById(2) != null);
    }
```

Comment: How can you do it one method? You clearly use different properties in each setup.  In one you use _dummies and in one you use _productTypes.  Can you change them to use a common property, e.g. Items and then we can help?

Comment: @Ruskin Yes that's a problem as well as I can't figure it out too :) How can I use a common field if the objects are different? Maybe I can use generic type, but I'm new to it and can't get it to work.

Comment: Okay, there is a solution but why are you adding the items from the mock to your private collections?

Comment: What are you testing? Show me your assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have over complicated your question and thus your solution. You don't need interfaces for your various repositories like *IDummyRepository* and *IProductRepository* if you are not adding any value to it.

Your data classes

```
public class Dummy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your ProductTypeService (I can only assume this)

```
public class ProductTypeService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ProductTypeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void AddProductType(ProductType productType)
    {
        _unitOfWork.ProductTypes.Add(productType);
    }
}
```

Your IUnitOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Dummy> Dummies { get; set; }
    IRepository<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Your IRepository remains unchanged so I won't copy paste it here!

Finally your unit test

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWorkMock;
    private Mock<IRepository<Dummy>> _dummyRepositoryMock;
    private Mock<IRepository<ProductType>> _productTypeRepositoryMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _dummyRepositoryMock = CreateMock<Dummy>();
        _productTypeRepositoryMock = CreateMock<ProductType>();

        _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(u => u.Dummies).Returns(_dummyRepositoryMock.Object);
        _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(u => u.ProductTypes).Returns(_productTypeRepositoryMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void product_type_service_should_add_item_to_the_underlying_repository()
    {
        var productTypeService = new ProductTypeService(_unitOfWorkMock.Object);
        var productType = new ProductType {Id = 10};
        productTypeService.AddProductType(productType);
        _productTypeRepositoryMock.Verify(r => r.Add(It.Is<ProductType>(p => p.Id == productType.Id)), Times.Once());
    }

    private Mock<IRepository<T>> CreateMock<T>() where T : class
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IRepository<T>>();

        // do more common magic here

        return mock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have your point on the overcomplicated repository layer in regards to YAGNI. I've change my repository layer using IRepository and implements your answer. You also give me some insight on how I should test. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you are testing the wrong thing; namely you are testing that an in-memory collection (a `List<T>`) can store data and the data can be found in the collection. **This always yields true because that is the purpose of in-memory collections**.

Instead of doing this you either need to create *integration tests* which will use the actual implementation of the underlying repository (such as `Entity Framework`) or just *test the behavior* of your service like this:

```
[Test]
public void ProductTypeService_WhenAddingNewItem_CallsSaveChanges()
{
    var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    // setup the properties of the mock here...

    var service = new ProductTypeService(unitOfWork);
    service.Add(new ProductType { Id = 2, Description = "some product" });

    unitOfWork.AssertWasCalled(_ => _.SaveChanges());
}
```

This way, you test that your service calls `SaveChanges()` method; actually saving the data is the responsibility of the repository and as I said above, testing that a list can store data in memory is useless.